Distribution when positive values are rescaled?
Suppose I have a series of gross P&L values, which are normally distributed with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$.
For positive P&L values, there is a $x\%$ commission. For example, $x=5\%$.
So the net pnl, $p_i$ is:

$p_i$ if $p_i$<0
$p_i * (1-x)$ if $p_i$>0

Given different $\mu%$ and $\sigma$, how can I calculate whether the net P&L over $n$ trades will be positive?

I assume you are looking for the expected value of a trade, so it does not really make sense to look at "P&L over $n$ trades", right?

OK. If so, what should I be doing?

A higher standard deviation will decrease the expected value. But I can't work out by how much. Intuitively, it might be something like (mu/signa) * (1-x)

How is the term net P&L defined? Is it: sum over $n$ trade PnLs, where at each trade $i$, if $p_i>0$, then payoff is $p_i(1-x)$?

As the payoff function is continuous, we can find the new density function by the change of variable for probability densities:
$$
\begin{align}
y&=r(x)\equiv\begin{cases} 
          x & x\leq 0 \\
          (1-\alpha)x & x> 0 
       \end{cases} \\
\end{align}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&=f_X(r^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy}(r^{-1}(y))\right|\\
&=\begin{cases} 
          f(y) & y\leq 0 \\
          \frac{f\left(\frac{y}{1-\alpha}\right)}{1-\alpha} & y> 0 
       \end{cases} 
\end{align}
$$
At closer expection, this is the weighted sum of the densities of two truncated normal variates. The MGF exists in closed form, thus we can easily produce mean, variance etc. As the MGF of a sum of independent RVs is the product of their individual MGFs, we could calculate the moments of the cumulative PnL over a number of individual PnLs using approximate methods.
It feels as if the derivation of the characteristic function would be too cumbersome, though...
So to answer your question: Either

simulate for varying parameters, or
calculate the first moments and use an Edgeworth expansion or similar.


I believe there is no "simple" answer to your question. To calculate the expected value of net return $n$ you could do the following:
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}(n) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t * f_n(t) dt \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{0} t * f_p(t) dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} t * (1-x) * f_p(t) dt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} t * f_p(t) dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} (t- tx) * f_p(t) dt \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} t * f_p(t) dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} t * f_p(t) dt  - x \int_{0}^{\infty} t * f_p(t) dt \\
&= \mathbb{E}(p) - x \int_{0}^{\infty} t * f_p(t) dt \end{align}$$
where $f_n$ denotes the density of the $n$ and $f_p$ denotes the density of $p$ (so the density of the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$).

If you expand this out you can clearly see the expectation is negative (if mu is zero), which makes sense because you are paying away comission on a RV which has expectation zero. Further you can observe that the expectation is exactly mu - 0.5x

You are right with the expansion. Just edited my answer to recover the expected value of p, but I do not see where you get the -0.5x.

(yes i was using symmetry with mu =0. when it is not zero doesnt look like a closed form)
